# Sagemaker Model Monitoring error while performing latest_execution.describe()

Tags: python, java, scala, apache-spark, amazon-sagemaker

I am trying to create a Model Monitor job for Sagemaker endpoint. The baseline constraints and statistics were computed successfully, but on scheduling a Monitoring Cron job, I am facing this error from Spark.

Dataset: [KC House Data](https://www.kaggle.com/shivachandel/kc-house-data)

```
monitor.create_monitoring_schedule(
endpoint_input=endpoint_input,
monitor_schedule_name=monitor_schedule_name,
post_analytics_processor_script=None,
output_s3_uri=monitor_report_path,
statistics=monitor.baseline_statistics(),
constraints=monitor.suggested_constraints(),
schedule_cron_expression=CronExpressionGenerator.hourly(),
enable_cloudwatch_metrics=True
)
monitor.describe_schedule()
```

Output: 
'MonitoringScheduleStatus': 'Scheduled'

```
import time
executions = []
while len(executions) == 0:
print('Checking for executions...')
executions = monitor.list_executions()
time.sleep(100)



latest_execution = monitor.list_executions()[-1]
latest_execution.wait(logs=True)
latest_execution.describe()
```

Output :

```
2022-03-11 06:07:24 INFO SparkContext:54 - Successfully stopped SparkContext
2022-03-11 06:07:24 ERROR Main:97 - Job aborted due to stage failure: Task 0 in stage 2.0 failed 4 times, most recent failure: Lost task 0.3 in stage 2.0 (TID 9, algo-1, executor 1): org.json4s.package$MappingException: Do not know how to convert JArray(List(JString(bedrooms), JString(bathrooms), JString(sqft_living), JString(sqft_above), JString(grade), JString(floors), JString(view), JString(sqft_lot), JString(floors), JString(waterfront), JString(zipcode))) into class java.lang.String
#011at org.json4s.Extraction$.convert(Extraction.scala:608)
#011at org.json4s.Extraction$.extract(Extraction.scala:350)
#011at org.json4s.Extraction$$anonfun$extract$5.apply(Extraction.scala:334)
#011at org.json4s.Extraction$$anonfun$extract$5.apply(Extraction.scala:334)
#011at scala.collection.immutable.List.map(List.scala:273)
#011at org.json4s.Extraction$.extract(Extraction.scala:334)
#011at org.json4s.Extraction$.extract(Extraction.scala:42)
```

Answer (score 0):

There could be multiple reasons why the Model Monitoring job could not get through in this case -

1. Assuming this is for [Model data quality monitoring](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/sagemaker/latest/dg/model-monitor-data-quality.html), I see that you are passing the baseline constraints and statistics file parameters correctly. I would check if the Data Capture job [ i.e Step 1 in this [example notebook](https://github.com/aws/amazon-sagemaker-examples/blob/main/sagemaker_model_monitor/introduction/SageMaker-ModelMonitoring.ipynb) ] outputs jsonl files as expected. Additionally, verify the baseline statistics and constraints has all the parameters and interprets the datatype of them accurately in your test dataset.
2. Instead of waiting for the schedule to run, you can use this [code construct](https://github.com/aws-samples/amazon-sagemaker-mlops-workshop/blob/main/labs/05_model_monitor/monitoringjob_utils.py) to trigger a processing job manually and verify its execution.